# Detecting Blow through iPhone MIC in Cocos and then Performing animation on an image

Tags: iphone, animation

I am working on an app which is related to the recipes.In this app there is a section where user can blow air through the mic and can change the image as well the content on it by using animation transition CurlDown.I am able to detect the blow by using the following code,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                              nil];

    NSError *error;

    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

    if (recorder) {
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [recorder record];

        levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


    }
    else{
//       NSLog([error description]);
    }

    image =[[UIImageView alloc] init];
    image.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Recipie.png"];
    image.frame =CGRectMake(50, 100, 150, 200);
    [self.view addSubview:image];

}


- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {

    [recorder updateMeters];
    const double ALPHA = 0.05;
    double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
    lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;  
//  NSLog(@"Average input: %f Peak input: %f Low pass results: %f", [recorder averagePowerForChannel:0], [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0], lowPassResults);
    if (lowPassResults >0.055 )
    {
        NSLog(@"Mic blow detected");
        [self changeFrame];

    }

}

-(void)changeFrame
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:image cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

But my problem is,when i blow first time through the mic then image animated 5 to 7 times and when i blow second time then images animates 9 to 10 times,i want this animation single times on every blow detection.
Please suggest me how can i do this using this code or it will be better for me if somebody can share the code for this section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem comes from the fact that you are calling `levelTimerCallback` each second. So, when a blow come in, for the whole duration of the blow your callback will make the image change.

A workaround to this would be using a BOOL flag:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL blowDetected;
```

In `levelTimerCallback`, you keep track of when a blow is detected and when it ends and you do change images only for new blows:

```
- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {

  [recorder updateMeters];
  const double ALPHA = 0.05;
  double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
  lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;  
  if (lowPassResults > 0.055)
  {
    NSLog(@"Blow detected with power: %f", lowPassResults);
    if (!self.blowDetected) {
      self.blowDetected = YES;
      NSLog(@"Mic blow detected");
      [self changeFrame];
    }
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Blow not detected with residual power: %f", lowPassResults);
    self.blowDetected = NO;
  }
}
```

This should prevent multiple image changes for the same blow...

Now, this will work fine when between a blow and the next one you wait enough time so that the power currently detected by the mic decreases below the `0.055` threshold. This means that any blow occurring before that will be ignored.

To improve this, instead of simply filtering the signal, we could simply try and detect when the filtered value increases; so I would suggest the following implementation:

```
- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {

  [recorder updateMeters];
  const double ALPHA = 0.05;
  double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
  double currentLowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;  
  if (currentLowPassResults > 0.055)
  {
    NSLog(@"Blow detected with power: %f", lowPassResults);
    if (!self.blowDetected || currentLowPassResult > K * lowPassResults) {
      self.blowDetected = YES;
      NSLog(@"Mic blow detected");
      [self changeFrame];
    }
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Blow not detected with residual power: %f", lowPassResults);
    self.blowDetected = NO;
  }
  lowPassResult = currentLowPassResults;
}
```

You could find an optimal value for K by doing some tests.

In the latter implementation:

1. when a blow is first detected, we change the image and go into mode "wait for blow to extinguish" (self.blowDetected == YES);
2. in mode "wait for blow to extinguish", we do not change images, unless we detect a new blow, characterized by the fact that we have a recording power significantly larger than the current level.

Comment: Thanks sergio for the quick response.I have added the same code that you have suggest here,after putting this code i am able to prevent multiple image changes for the same blow but not able to get the same effect for second attempt.

Comment: Whenever user will blow through the mic than single image will animate,that is what i need to do with this code.Please do share your ideas over this.I'll be very thankful to you.

Comment: I added a couple of NSLog traces to get a more precise idea of what is happening. Could you run the program and post the NSLog output, please?

Comment: Yes,i am getting this one only once like:2012-10-21 01:41:00.118 MicBlow[5666:307] Mic blow detected

Comment: sorry: there should be the two NSLog I added to my answer as well... check my answer again, please...

Comment: Hey,it's working but with some minor error there,When i blow first time then it animate image single times but soon if i blow onto the mic then it didn't change the image but if i took some time for second attempt then it's work.Please suggest how to overcome this issue.

Comment: 2012-10-21 01:49:19.612 MicBlow[5687:307] Blow not detected with residual power: 0.009630
2012-10-21 01:49:20.613 MicBlow[5687:307] Mic blow detected
2012-10-21 01:49:32.612 MicBlow[5687:307] Blow not detected with residual power: 0.054793

Comment: please, see my edit; indeed, this is a pretty rough solution, but I hope it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sergio,it's working perfectly.I have changed the frequency as well as the timer value from 1 to 0.05 which is detecting each blow and animating image as well.Thanks again for guiding me.

Answer (score 3):

Use return as you get first lowpass results >0.55

I have solve the issue have a look.

```
-(void)readyToBlow1 {

  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

  NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];

NSError *error;

recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

if (recorder) {
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder record];
    levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.01 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback1:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
 } 
  else
     NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);

}

 - (void)levelTimerCallback1:(NSTimer *)timer {

    [recorder updateMeters];

const double ALPHA = 0.05;
double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;
//NSLog(@"lowPassResults= %f",lowPassResults);

if (lowPassResults > 0.55)
{

    lowPassResults = 0.0;

    [self invalidateTimers];


    NextPhase *objNextView =[[NextPhase alloc]init];

    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view
                        toView:objNextView.view
                      duration:2.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    }
     ];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objNextView animated:NO];

    **return;**


  }

}
```